# UPDATE with GROUP BY for all records in relation

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, join

I have 2 tables `word_lists` and `memo_words`, word_list has many memo_words (1 - n).

```
TABLE: word_lists
+----+----------+----------------+
| id | name     | average_rating |
+----+----------+----------------+
| 1  | example1 |       ?        |
| 2  | example2 |       ?        |
| 3  | example3 |       ?        |
+----+----------+----------------+
ID is primary

TABLE: memo_words
+----+----------+-------+-------------------+
| id | name     | rating| word_list_id      |
+----+----------+-------+-------------------+
| 1  | random1  |  153  | 1                 |
| 2  | random2  |  158  | 1                 |
| 3  | random3  |  167  | 1                 |
+----+----------+-------+-------------------+
ID is primary
```

I would like to calculate word_lists.average_rating for every word_lists record. Average rating It's a average from memo_words.rating for every memo_words record in relation. For calculate average I could use simply something like this:

```
  SELECT id, AVG(rating) from memo_words group_by word_list_id;
```

But how I could update word_lists records ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is:

```
Update word_list
    set average_rating = (select AVG(mw.rating)
                          from memo_words mw
                          where mw.word_list_id = word_list.id
                         )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Update word_lists w inner join 
(select AVG(rating) rating,word_list_id from memo_words
 group by word_list_id) m on w.id=m.word_list_id
set w.average_rating=m.rating
```

Try this

Answer (score 1):

Here is the MySQL `UPDATE` syntax with `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE word_lists w
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT 
     word_list_id,
     AVG(rating) averageRating
   FROM memo_words 
   GROUP BY word_list_id
) m ON w.Id = m.word_list_id
SET w.average_rating = m.averageRating;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ce0f/1)

This will make your table `memo_words` looks like:

```
| ID |     NAME | AVERAGE_RATING |
----------------------------------
|  1 | example1 |            159 |
|  2 | example2 |         (null) |
|  3 | example3 |         (null) |
```